# Why shouldn't I use global variables in JavaScript for something that's constant?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I've heard that global variables in JavaScript are bad, and I can understand some of the namespace issues, etc. But why shouldn't I use a global variable for something that never gets changed throughout the script--like the date? (Which changes day to day, of course, but only ever gets referenced and not changed throughout the script.)

Comment: How would the variable not changing invalidate the namespace concerns?

Comment: `const brain = "I think people forget const";`

Comment: It doesn't. But it seems like a global variable could be named something unique. (like global_date or something)

Comment: Namespaces in JS are no more than global variables themselves. Do I need a namepsace (read: global variable) for the namespace (read: global variable), a namespace (read: global variable) for that namespace (read: global variable), etc (to infinity)? Nope. Some things need to be global.

Comment: @trinithis: one global variable is less worse than lots of globals.

Comment: I know. I just hate the nomenclature/connotations of "namespaces" in javascript. That is, people always say globals are bad, and namespaces are good. Thing is, namespaces are globals. Instead say most globals are bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use globals if they are protected in what you think is a unique namespace and are only used when beneficial.  The main issue is that globals can make one piece of code more likely to conflict with some other piece of code (if not using different namespaces or very unique names).  For this reason and others, it is best to avoid globals when they are not actually needed (when variables declared local to some scope would work just as well), but there are still some appropriate reasons to have globals.  The main point of education is that many people use globals when they are simply not needed.  If you need them or find they are more efficient, then you can use them just fine as long as you protect the namespace from accidental collision.

I personally create one top level, global object and hang all my other globals off that one object.

Some other issues with globals:

1. They are slower to access in Javascript than locals because they are the last ones found as the interpreter looks for a given variable name in the various scopes that it might exist in.  Usually not a noticeable problem, but something to be aware of.  Here's a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/global-var-speed-test) that shows how much of a difference there can be.
2. If you have any asynchronous code that modifies globals or timer-driven code that modifies globals and more than one asynchronous operation can be in flight at the same time, the multiple async operations can step on each other through the modification of the same globals.
3. Globals are often not declared near the point of use so reading code can be more challenging.
4. Globals are generally not shown automatically in the debugger (the way local variables are) making debugging a little less convenient.
5. IE automatically defines a bunch of global variables based on some names in the DOM which can conflict with your own global variables without you realizing it.
6. A simple omission of the keyword "var" on a local variable makes it a global variable and can confuse the heck out of code if that name is already being used as an intended global variable.  I've seen this happen on the `for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++)` construct before.  It can be tough to track down what is wrong.
7. Global variables persist for the life of the script.  If one is using a global variable to hold an object reference for something that doesn't need to exist for the life of the script, this can cause the script to use more memory than it otherwise would.
8. Global variables in a browser exist in the scope of the `window` object so they can conflict not only with other globals, but also anything else on the window object.

Comment: 1 you shouldn't care about unless it becomes a problem, and 2 could potentially be true of function level variables too. 3 is a great point though :) +1

Comment: Can you explain #2 a bit more? I'm not clear how async operations could interact through read-only access to constants, because read doesn't block. My understanding is that conflict could only occur if shared vars actually change.

Comment: I explained #2 a bit more and added a few more points.  #2 is only a problem if you are modifying globals.  Read-only globals are only an issue if there's a naming collision.

Comment: I usually attach things that are logically global to a page singleton(itself a global object). Something like AppPageConstants = {const1='const1',const2='const2'}. I am not sure if this is the best idea though but it is better than just scattering your constants IMO.

Comment: About 1. That all depends on the interpreter. It would be very easy to make a dictionary (hash O(1) / tree O(nlogn) / whatever) of variable names that map to a stack of variables, where the top of each stack is the one in the most local scope.

Comment: @trinithis - I'm not sure what point you're trying to make, but variables exist in a given scope (each a separate data structure).  By definition of the JS language, local variables must be searched first.  If a given variable reference is not found there, then the other accessible scopes up the call stack are searched next, eventually looking in the global scope.  Since the global scope is searched last (and has to be based on how the language works), vars in the global scope will always be found last (and thus more slowly).

Comment: I'm just saying that it is possible to have the implementation lookup variables in a fashion much like a standard symbol table, in which case lookup could be constant. Not saying that this is the best way of implementing it in JS though because other factors (nothing in particular... just runtime stuff) are at play as well.

Comment: I realize that it would be possible to flatten a namespace for each particular scope and have all vars accessible in that space be equal access time, but the process of creating such a flattened name space would probably ruin any performance gains one might get.  Here's a jsperf that shows the speed difference (50-100%) http://jsperf.com/global-var-speed-test.

Comment: Wow, lots of insight from all. Thanks so much.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know this is an old answer, but about # 2 I was hit by it recently and I can't figure out why. Could you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852823/global-variables-in-asynchronous-code-socket-io-show-an-error-in-an-unexpected ?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest answer is namespace issues. If you include another script that uses the same variable name it will have side effects that are undesired. If you can ensure no other script will be included in the future on that page, then it's less of an issue for you specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use global variables in javascript because of possible conflicts with other scripts. For example you are writting jQuery plugin. Your global variables may overwrite global variables from another script.

So, to reduce this rewritable possibility to minimum you should use only one global variable. If you use jQuery you shouldn't use global variables at all. You can extend global $ object.
For example:

```
$.extend({
    something: your_app_variable
});
```

If you use pure javascript than you should use namespacing issue. Create only one global variable for your application. All other variables will be only the properties of this global variables.
For example:

```
// if APP doesn't exist creating it
APP = APP || {};
APP.some_method = function(){}
APP.some_property = 3;
```

UPD: Remember that you should declare variables with `var`. Unless the declared variable will be global. Errors, caused by forgetting `var` keyword are difficult to catch