# Matching Data to an Array and return a value

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to design a function that has an array like the below and use an if statement to check if the type is equal to the following in any of my categories in my array below and return its associate category code?

Example:

```
function CheckCategory(type) {

array = 

[NOTES, CAT-A],
[BOOKS, CAT-B],
[MUSIC, CAT-C],
[SOFTWARE, CAT-D]

if (type == "NOTES") { return "CAT-A" }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare your `array` variable as a two-dimensional array (an array of arrays):

```
function checkCategory(type) {
    var array = [
        ['NOTES', 'CAT-A'],
        ['BOOKS', 'CAT-B'],
        ['MUSIC', 'CAT-C'],
        ['SOFTWARE', 'CAT-D']
    ];

    // Then, simply loop over your array and check for the type
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (type == array[i][0]) {

            // It will return the CAT-X of the matching type
            return array[i][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you could declare your variable as an object, and return the value of `type` property:

```
function checkCategory(type) {
    var values = {
        NOTES: 'CAT-A',
        BOOKS: 'CAT-B',
        MUSIC: 'CAT-C',
        SOFTWARE: 'CAT-D'
    }

    return values[type];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
var CatTable={"NOTES": "CAT-A", "BOOKS": "CAT-B", "MUSIC": "CAT-C", "SOFTWARE": "CAT-D"};

function  CheckCategory(type) {
  if (CatTable[type]) return CatTable[type];
  else return "UNKNOWN CATEGORY"
}
```

Comment: Why is `CatTable` global (or at least outside of `CheckCategory`)?

Comment: I assumed, it might also be needed elswhere

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use global variables...?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989918/402037)

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckCategory(type) {
    var data = [
        ['NOTES', 'CAT-A'],
        ['BOOKS', 'CAT-B'],
        ['MUSIC', 'CAT-C'],
        ['SOFTWARE', 'CAT-D']
    ];

    for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] == type) {
            return data[i][1];   
        }
    }

    return "Not found";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/5s8wr/2/