# How can I pull a variable from an html script to a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, chat

How can I take the `user` variable from an HTML script and use it in my index.js file?

```
<script>      
function getUsername() {
   var user = cookie.get('user');
      if (!user) {

         // Ask for the username if there is none set already
         user = prompt('Choose a username:');
         if (!user) {
            alert('You must select a username...');
            getUsername();
          } else {
            // Store it in the cookies for future use
            cookie.set('user', user);
          }
        }  
      }  
</script>
```

I want to take the `user` variable and put it in my js file. How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of creating a global variable, you could just return the username from your function

Answer (score -2):

To define a global variable, that can be accessed from any script on your page, you can use the `window` object like

```
var user = cookie.get('user');
window.user = user;
```

Then you can access `window.user` from another script, like a React application.

Here is a [discussion about why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript), and there, as The Head Rush pointed out correctly in their comment, some counterpoint about the drawbacks of attaching globals to the window :

Comment: And some counterpoint about the drawbacks of attaching globals to the `window`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989903/why-shouldnt-i-use-global-variables-in-javascript-for-something-thats-constant

Comment: Good point @TheHeadRush , thanks for adding the link! I agree that there are good reasons to avoid using window as a state store.